# Youtube Video Player Playing Last Video Only

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

Using a google embeded player with `JS`

I have two players on a `.php page`

The first video does not play and the second one does.

I am pretty sure cause I am overriding the first function with the second. 
Where am I going wrong with this?

Video 0

```
  <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player0"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player0;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player0 = new YT.Player('player0', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player0.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
```

Video 1

```
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player1"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player1;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player1.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you are overwriting your functions. `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`, for example, will only create the second player. As you can guess, it should be written that way:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    //declare your first player
    //declare your second player
}
```

The `done` variable from the Youtube API documentation was meant for only one player. If you want multiple ones, you should create multiple variables, or an array. But for clarity, I will not go into that.

**Example for creating multiple players and making them play:**

```
<div id="player0"></div>
<div id="player1"></div>

<script>

    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player0, player1;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player0 = new YT.Player('player0', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });

        player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        //do something with 'event.target' if you need to
    }

</script>
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Need more examples or explanations? Just tell us.

Comment: Thank you so much. You explained it all so well.